# Hide a UIbutton when another UIbutton is pressed

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have a record button, which when pressed, I want to hide the instructions button.

Here's the code for the record button:

```
// Create custom overlay
// Create instruction/record button
// Add instruction/record button to custom overlay
[_videoRecordBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(startVideoRecord:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

So in startVideoRecord I should have something like:

```
-(IBAction)startVideoRecord:(id)sender{
    [_instru setHidden:YES];
    // start recording...
}
```

But I have no idea how to pass the `_instru` button over to `startVideoRecord`.

Comment: Make your ``instru`` be a property of a class. Then you can access it through ``self.instru`` and set it to ``self.instru.hidden = YES;`` anywhere in your class.

Comment: Can you explain __pass the _instru button over to startVideoRecord__ ?

Comment: you can make _instru button global on defining it on .h file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a property to your ViewController to keep a reference to your instructionsButton:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *instructionsButton;
```

When you create your instructionsButton, assign it to this property.

Then you can access the button via this property anywhere in your ViewController with `self. instructionsButton`.

So, your action method would be like:

```
-(IBAction)startVideoRecord:(id)sender{
    self.instructionsButton.hidden = YES;
    // start recording...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by 2 way..

1 way - > you set the `tag of instructions button`.

and use this

```
-(IBAction)startVideoRecord:(id)sender{

UIButton *instruBtn = (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:your button tag];


instruBtn.hidden = YES;

// start recording...
}
```

2nd Way - > you make property for your instructions button and use like this

```
  -(IBAction)startVideoRecord:(id)sender{

    self.instruBtn.hidden = YES;

    // start recording...
    }
```